# Proper Abbreviation of "Servant of God" in Catholic Writings?

Tags: catholicism

When writing, we may abbreviate "Saint" as *St.* or *S.* (in olden times).

"Blessed" as *Bl.*

But how, in English, may one abbreviate "Servant of God"? In particular, I would like to make reference to *Servant of God John A. Hardon, S.J.* in something I am writing by shortening "Servant of God" to something that uses two or three letters.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: I believe that you can use SOG or SG. You could also use S.D. (Servus Dei, which means servant of God in Latin)

Comment: @jaredad7 Thank you for your comment; do you know if one of them is the generally accepted  abbreviation? I don't ever recall seeing the term abbreviated before in English---but without abbreviation, there are many words to write.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I couldn't find any trustworthy sources giving an abbreviation.

Comment: @jaredad7 One may think such a thing would be easy, but I've never identified how to do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proper Abbreviation of "Servant of God" in Catholic Writings?**

The Catholic abbreviation for a Servant of God is **S.D.** after the Latin equivalent ***Servus Dei***!

> S.D. — Servus Dei (Servant of God) - [Ecclesiastical Abbreviations](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01022a.htm)

If you reference the Servant of God, Fr. John Hardon S.J., you should print out his title as I just did for the first time in a document or letter. After this you could abbreviate his title to the S.D. John Hardon (SJ). The abbreviation S.J. for *Societas Iesu* could be omitted if desired.

The title ***Servant of God*** is not considered a canonical title in a strict sense by the Catholic Church, but only a technical term used in the process of canonization.

Comment: Would it then be John A. Hardon, S.J., S.D. or S.D. John A Hardon, S.J.. or something else?

Comment: In the list your provide, I was surprised not to find the expected abbreviations for Saint, Blessed, and Venerable.

Comment: +1 Is there anything New Advent doesn't have available on some obscure page?